# Improper margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I am completing a new project and run into this problem. On the left side, there is more space than on the right side. I have tried plenty of solutions but none worked.
[image]

Here is my CSS code for body and main:

```
body {
  font-family: $font;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: url(/images/bg-pattern-top-desktop.svg),
    url(/images/bg-pattern-bottom-desktop.svg);
  background-position: top left, top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
main {
  height: 70%;
}
```

The link for the whole code is also provided:
https://codepen.io/kyrylolvov-the-looper/pen/rNMYOwE

Comment: Include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in **the body of your question** in accordance with Stack Overflow's [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Links to external sites tend to break and nuke value for future visitors to your question.

Comment: Do you every box stuck with the bottom. at equal height above the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `align-items:flex-end;` on `.second-row` and this will appear correctly :)

```
.second-row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end; // Add this line of code
}
```

**CODEPEN WORKING LINK:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/jOMabaQ